# Java generics: multiple generic parameters?

Tags: java, generics, parameters

I was wondering if it's possible to write a function that accepts multiple generic types as follows:

```
public int void myfunction(Set<T> a, Set<T> b) {
    return 5;
}

Set<Integer> setA = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<String>();
int result = myfunction(setA, setB);
```

Will that work? Does the  generic in each parameter mean that each parameter must have the same type T that's generic?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Yes - it's possible (though not with your method signature) and yes, with your signature the types must be the same.

With the signature you have given, `T` must be associated to a single type (e.g. `String` **or** `Integer`) at the call-site. You can, however, declare method signatures which take multiple type parameters

```
public <S, T> void func(Set<S> s, Set<T> t)
```

Note in the above signature that I have declared the types `S` and `T` in the signature itself. These are therefore different to and independent of any generic types associated with the class or interface which contains the function.

```
public class MyClass<S, T> {
   public        void foo(Set<S> s, Set<T> t); //same type params as on class
   public <U, V> void bar(Set<U> s, Set<V> t); //type params independent of class
}
```

You might like to take a look at some of the method signatures of the collection classes in the `java.util` package. Generics is really rather a complicated subject, especially when wildcards (`? extends` and `? super`) are considered. For example, it's often the case that a method which might take a `Set<Number>` as a parameter should also accept a `Set<Integer>`. In which case you'd see a signature like this:

```
public void baz(Set<? extends T> s);
```

There are plenty of questions already on SO for you to look at on the subject!

- [Java Generics: List, List<Object>, List<?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics)
- [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)
- [What are the differences between Generics in C# and Java... and Templates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-and-java-and-templates-in-c)

Not sure what the point of returning an `int` from the function is, although you could do that if you want!

Comment: I don't understand why it's "Yes" to both questions (specifically, why "Yes" to "Will this work?"). The function above (contrived, I know, with the int-return) won't accept the two different types since it expects the same generic type T for both parameters, right?

Comment: Sorry - I meant "yes it's possible" and "yes, in the signature you defined, the types need to be the same"

Answer (score 12):

Even more, you can inherit generics :)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Something<E>, E extends Enum<E> & SomethingAware> T getSomething(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T) somethingHolderMap.get(clazz);
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can follow one of the below approaches:

1) Basic, single type :

```
//One type
public static <T> void fill(List <T> list, T val) {

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        list.set(i, val);
    }

}
```

2) Multiple Types :

```
// multiple types as parameters
public static <T1, T2> String multipleTypeArgument(T1 val1, T2 val2) {

    return val1+" "+val2;

}
```

3) Below will raise compiler error as 'T3 is not in the listing of generic types that are used in function declaration part.

```
//Raised compilation error
public static <T1, T2> T3 returnTypeGeneric(T1 val1, T2 val2) {
    return 0;
}
```

Correct : Compiles fine

```
public static <T1, T2, T3> T3 returnTypeGeneric(T1 val1, T2 val2) {
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Class Code :

```
package generics.basics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericMethods {

/*
 Declare the generic type parameter T in this method. 

 After the qualifiers public and static, you put <T> and 
 then followed it by return type, method name, and its parameters.

 Observe : type of val is 'T' and not '<T>'

 * */
//One type
public static <T> void fill(List <T> list, T val) {

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        list.set(i, val);
    }

}

// multiple types as parameters
public static <T1, T2> String multipleTypeArgument(T1 val1, T2 val2) {

    return val1+" "+val2;

}

/*// Q: To audience -> will this compile ? 
 * 
 * public static <T1, T2> T3 returnTypeGeneric(T1 val1, T2 val2) {

    return 0;

}*/

 public static <T1, T2, T3> T3 returnTypeGeneric(T1 val1, T2 val2) {

    return null;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(20);
    System.out.println(list.toString());
    fill(list, 100);
    System.out.println(list.toString());

    List<String> Strlist = new ArrayList<>();
    Strlist.add("Chirag");
    Strlist.add("Nayak");
    System.out.println(Strlist.toString());
    fill(Strlist, "GOOD BOY");
    System.out.println(Strlist.toString());


    System.out.println(multipleTypeArgument("Chirag", 100));
    System.out.println(multipleTypeArgument(100,"Nayak"));

}

}
```

// class definition ends

Sample Output:

```
[10, 20]
[100, 100]
[Chirag, Nayak]
[GOOD BOY, GOOD BOY]
Chirag 100
100 Nayak
```

Answer (score 10):

You can declare multiple type variables on a type or method. For example, using type parameters on the method:

```
<P, Q> int f(Set<P>, Set<Q>) {
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a and b must both be sets of the same type. But nothing prevents you from writing

```
myfunction(Set<X> a, Set<Y> b)
```

Comment: Except that you need to declare the type parameters in the signature as in my answer

Comment: You shouldn't accept a wrong answer.  @oxbow_lakes was the first one to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

In your function definition you're constraining sets a and b to the same type. You can also write

```
public <X,Y> void myFunction(Set<X> s1, Set<Y> s2){...}
```