# Overcome type erasure in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I have a client class which I cannot change.

```
List<Integer> list1= Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
System.out.println("Total sum is:"+sum(list1));
printlist(list1);
List<Double> list2=Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0);
System.out.println("Total sum is:"+sum(list2));
printlist(list2);
```

I have the business logic here

```
private static Object sum(List<? extends Number> list) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (Number i: list) {
        sum+=i.doubleValue();
    }     
    return sum;
}
```

So I want to return 6 for integer and 6.0 for a double. How can I do that? I am thinking to typecast sum as int or double based on type but due to type erasure all the info is lost. Can someone help me?

Comment: What if it's a mix of `Integer` and `Double`?

Comment: Right now I am not checking that condition. I am just trying to understand generics. I am a newbie to generics

Comment: There's no way to find out what type of list it is other than by checking its contents.

Comment: So the 'business logic' method you can change?

Comment: you can use override, even java does that

Comment: or look into following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759549/java-generics-multiple-generic-parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects in the list still have type information associated to them at run time. The only erased types are those of the generics (i.e. `List` in your example). The generics are checked at compile time, but are not maintained in the generated bytecode. That means you can use `instanceof` to check the *contents* of the collection:

```
private static Object sum(List<? extends Number> list) {
    Integer integerSum = 0;
    Double doubleSum = 0.0;
    boolean hasDouble = false;
    for (Number i: list) {
        if (i instanceof Integer) {
            integerSum += i.intValue();
        } else {
            doubleSum += i.doubleValue();
            hasDouble = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasDouble)
        return doubleSum + integerSum;
    return integerSum;
}
```

The code has some peculiarities to handle mixed lists, and doesn't handle `Long`, `Short`, `Byte` etc. properly.

Comment: You don't need to call the `Double` constructor. Just return `doubleSum + integerSum`.

Comment: You can use double to sum all values and cast it at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Use 'instanceof"

```
     if( i instanceof Double) {
       System.out.println("param is a Double");
     }
     else if( i instanceof Integer) {
       System.out.println("param is an Integer");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is dangerous to assume that a `Number` subclass instance can be represented with `double`. To do this safely, you need to check for all possible types.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Number> T sum(List<T> list) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(list);

    if (list.isEmpty() || list.contains(null))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) list.get(0).getClass();

    if (clazz == Integer.class) {
        return (T) (Integer) list.stream().mapToInt(i -> (Integer) i).sum();
    }
    else if (clazz == Double.class) {
        return (T) (Double) list.stream().mapToDouble(i -> (Double) i).sum();
    }
    /* And other Number subclass types */

    // Not possible if all types covered
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214469/2970960) is a question/answer related to this.