# What do the paired "<" and ">" symbols mean in Java? (For example, ArrayList<String>)

Tags: java

I am familiar with using parentheses, as in `myMethod(myParameter)`, in Java and other programming languages, but what do the lesser than `<` and greater than `>` signs mean when they are used together in a array name? Is there a special name for them?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I don't know how to search for this.

**Clarification:** I wasn't referring to the role of any specific type inside the symbols, but rather the usage of the `<>` symbols themselves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017253/what-is-the-role-of-the-data-types-inside-of-in-java?lq=1

Comment: They mean you need to learn more of the Java language :-)

Comment: Thanks. Java Generics is what I wanted. I just didn't know what it was called. Too bad it cost me down votes to get the answer, though. :(

Comment: You got two donvotes for a rep of -4. Here's an upvote for +10. Quit your whining :-) (note the smiley!).

Comment: @paxdiablo, you're right. I was going to edit out the whining from my comment, but I think I passed some editing time limit. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It's a fair enough question.  If you don't know what it's called, you don't know what to search for, either in Google (or some other search engine), or on Stack Overflow.  Googling `<` doesn't help much, since there are so many other uses for this symbol.  I think the people who downvoted this question didn't really think things through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is java generics, for type safe, and always.using with collections.

i suggest you read the SCJP book, it has a chapter called Generics and Collections, it provides all details you will need, it really helpful. hope it helps.

Comment: To the downvoter: it would be polite to state _why_ you think this answer isn't useful. That would make it easier for author to fix whatever problem exists, or state why you're incorrect (assuming that's the case).

Comment: @paxdiablo - maybe because of this - "and always.using with collections"

Comment: i wanted to say generics is always bundle with collections, for example, Queue, List, Map and so on

Comment: Thanks for a reference to the SCJP book. Here is a link for anyone else who might find it useful. https://java.net/downloads/jfjug/SCJP%20Sun%20Certified%20Programmer%20for%20Java%206-0071591060.pdf

Comment: By reading the SCJP book I learned that <> are called angle brackets.