# In java what's the difference between ?, E, T

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics)

Hi,

Can anyone please explain the difference of the three and each proper usage?

Thanks, been googling but I'm still confused on how to use each.

czetsuya

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: are you asking about generics parameters?

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about Generics.  The 'E' and 'T' are placeholders and can be used interchangeably in class definitions.  By convention 'E' is an Element and 'T' is a Type.  The question mark is a placeholder for an unknown type.  You often see things like this:

```
List<? extends MyObject> x;
```

This implies that 'x' is a list of objects that are subclasses of MyObject, but we don't know what they are exactly.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html

Answer (score 5):

E, T, K, V, or any other generic type variables are just placeholders - they don't have any intrinsic association.  You can even use lowercase letters for generic type variables, but conventionally you use a single capital letter.  Read the generics [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) from Sun.