# Java class definition

Tags: java, class

I am trying to understand what is this java class definition.

```
abstract public class A<P extends B<?, ?>,Input,Output>
{
...
// class defined
...
}
```

A c++ programmer moving to java

Comment: im a c++ programmer too, slightly dabbling in java, and to me that looks like STL template definitions :)

Comment: duplicate of many like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics

Comment: +1 for @MeBigFatGuy's username-lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This defines an abstract class called `A`, with three type parameters:

- `P`, which must be of type `B` (with any type arguments) or any type derived from it
- `Input`, of any type
- `Output`, of any type

Of interest is the first type parameter. In C++, for a type-based template parameter, you can supply any type; in Java, you have the option to constrain the type by what class and/or interfaces such a type must also extend/implement.

Comment: thanks, can u provide some links explaining java classes taking parameters

Comment: @Kazoom: Those classes are called "generic" classes. Read the link given by MeBigFatGuy in the question's comments.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of "translation":

"abstract" means this class may have abstract (~=pure virtual) methods.

class A is a generic (~template) definition

P extends ... is an extra constraint on generic parameter, should be subclass of ...

P extends B<?, ?> means that the generic parameter#1 is a subclass of another generic class

Comment: It might not have pure virtuals. Abstract classes in Java only have the property of not being directly instantiatable in and of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It's an abstract class definition (obviously) with 3 generic parameters.

The first parameter P has a constraint that it has to be of type (or that extends) class/interface B which has two generic parameters (no constraint on those) so it could be like

```
public class B<T1, T2> {

}
```

The second and third parameters namely Input and Output have no constraints.

Answer (score -1):

The angle bracket notation is for [Java Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).

Comment: -1 You'd think that C++ people already know what generics are, surely? C++ templates are much beefier than Java generics.

Comment: the main difference being in c++ each specialization creates a separate class, whereas in java the specialization is lost at compile time.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: well... *after* compilation phase is complete... Java generics just aren't reified like C++ generics are.

Comment: @Chris: Generics != C++ templates, and it's not clear the OP had run across the term before.

Comment: +1 to @Jim: Java Generics and C++ templates share only superficial similarity. They use a similar syntax and Java generics approach a subset of the problems approached by C++ templates, but their implementation and are quite different!

Answer (score -1):

Well, to really understand it you'd want to include more of the definition, but B is a class with generics itself, and A has three generic references in it; it's a bit pathological, but it's fairly easy to step through.