# Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I need a tutorial about Generics in java, the [tutorial documents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) on the Oracle website are very confusing, can anyone give some resources about Generics?

Comment: [This earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics) has some links to resources as well as its own great description.  The book referenced in the accepted answer is the best resource you will find.

Comment: how is the document too confusing?

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks guys for providing me such good tutoiral!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could try to read .pdf on generics in java [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the official Java tutorial on generics: [Lesson: Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html). It provides a really gentle introduction with hands on examples.

Angelika Langer maintains a quite good [FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to know that generics are way to enforce compile time checking of your code to make sure the Objects in a collection are the object you think it is.  Otherwise you can get ClassCastExceptions and other nasty run-time errors if the Object in a list is a Number when you thought it was a String.

Answer (score 0):

You should have googled 
well Try to go through Josh Bloch stuff,The creater of great generics,secondly, I guess generics tutorials at [Oracle  Site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) is most basic in nature.Dont expect easy stuff than that

1. [Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOwHiGCzZjo)
2. [Tut](http://www.gridshore.nl/blog/index.php?/archives/67-Java-Generics-almost-seem-like-puzzlers-from-Joshua-Bloch.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the Generics chapter in Herb Schildt's Java Complete Reference. Its a very gentle learning curve. If you want advanced treatise , go for the O'Reilly book Java Generics ( and collections )...