# When are the situations when those brackets < > are used in Java?

Tags: java

I mean those brackets < >

thanks a lot, world class experts on Stack Overflow!!

Comment: You mean [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)?

Comment: Do you mean the diamond syntax added in Java 7 ie `<>` or plain generics added 7 years ago?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809339/generics-in-java

Answer (score 6):

Let's not forget numeric comparisons!

Answer (score 4):

They're used to denote [generic types and methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

So for instance, the following:

```
class Foo<T> {
    void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    private T t;
}
```

is a generic class paramterised on `T`.  It's used to enforce type-safety, thus:

```
class X {}
class Y {}

Foo<X> foo_x = new Foo<X>();
Foo<Y> foo_y = new Foo<Y>();

foo_x.set(new X());  // ok
foo_y.set(new Y());  // ok
foo_x.set(new Y());  // compiler error!
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to generics and numeric comparisons, there's also bitwise operations. Can't remember ever doing that in java though.

Comment: +1, yeah. (I've used them for that! But forgot.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Generics.

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
```