# ArrayList<T> vs ArrayList<?>

Tags: java, generics

I know what `ArrayList<T>` is used for, but when should I use `ArrayList<?>` ? can you explain with example? thanks.

Comment: In practice, `<?>` is almost never used on its own. Wildcards are useful with `extends` and `super`.

Comment: If I recall correctly, ArrayList<?> is just short for ArrayList<? extends Object>.   So in a sense, <?> is never used on its own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Different between List, List<?>, List<T>, List<E>, and List<Object>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231973/java-different-between-list-list-listt-liste-and-listobject)

Comment: I tried to give you an example that should help you understand. Let me know if you more questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I've been able to tell, `ArrayList<?>` basically tells the compiler:

> Yes, I know that there is a generic version of ArrayList available to me, but I really, genuinely don't know what kind of objects I'm expecting to be in this one. So don't give me warnings that I'm not using generics the way I should be.

#### Update

I just learned that there is a real difference between using Raw Types (`ArrayList`) and generics with wildcards (`ArrayList<?>`) that goes beyond avoiding compiler warnings. Apparently once you declare something as a Raw type, no generics will work on any methods of that type, even if the generics weren't based on the type you omitted. [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423150/compilation-error-with-generic).

So while my original answer was generally correct, I thought it would be important to mention that using `ArrayList<?>` instead of `ArrayList` is more than just a matter of removing compiler warnings.

Comment: there are more differences between raw types and types with wildcard parameters. For example, you can add objects to a raw ArrayList, but not to an `ArrayList<?>`

Comment: @newacct: I don't think that's true. While I don't have a Java environment available right now, adding objects to an `ArrayList<?>` seems to work just fine on the Groovy Console: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/550003

Comment: that shouldn't work in Java (producer extends, consumer super). also, you can't even have `new ArrayList<?>()` in Java, so maybe Groovy is a little different

Comment: @newacct: I got a chance to play with a Java environment, and it looks like you're right on both counts. Excellent observations.

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayList<?>` indicates a collection of an unknown object, that is, it can be anything. It is possible to read from it, but you cannot write to it.

It sounds something like that:

> I am a collection! I can read the unknown, but since I do not know what its type, I cannot add stuff

see this very useful [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) by Oracle.

Also, I find these [slides](http://stellar.mit.edu/S/course/6/sp11/6.005/courseMaterial/topics/topic2/lectureNotes/Generics-spring11/Generics-spring11.pdf) from an MIT Software Construction class very useful, and this generics [tutorial](http://stellar.mit.edu/S/course/6/sp11/6.005/courseMaterial/topics/topic2/studyMaterial/generics-tutorial/generics-tutorial.pdf).

Comment: So, is this a clever way to, at compile time, way a read-only list? But then again, what use would it be because you can't get any data into it?!

Answer (score 5):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

> Note: It's also possible to specify a lower bound by using the super
>   keyword instead of extends. The code `<? super Animal>`, therefore,
>   would be read as "an unknown type that is a supertype of Animal,
>   possibly Animal itself". **You can also specify an unknown type with an
>   unbounded wildcard, which simply looks like `<?>`. An unbounded wildcard
>   is essentially the same as saying `<? extends Object>`.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete example. Let's say you have a

```
class Base {}
```

Then class `Extender extends Base{}`

Now if you have `Collection<Extender> collection` and you want to call it using this method.

```
public void doSomething(Collection<Base> c){...}
```

**Above will not work or copmpile**. What will work is

```
doSomething(Collection<? extends Base> c)
```

This basically says that I don't care what type `?` is but it has to extend Base. Now that you get that, it will help you understand what `?` mean. It the same as using `<? extends Object>`

Comment: As a corollary: If you put Collection<? super Base> c it would mean only super classes of Base, including Base itself, are accepted? Looking for confirmation