# Compilation error with generic

Tags: java, generics

Where is the difference between test1 and test2?
Why compilation error in test1?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

class MyType {

}

class MyClass<T> {
    private Collection<MyType> myTypes = new ArrayList<MyType>();
    private Collection<T> myTs = new ArrayList<T>();

    public Collection<MyType> getMyTypes() {
        return myTypes;
    }

    public Collection<T> getMyTs() {
        return myTs;
    }
}



public class TestSimple {

    public void test1() {    

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        for (MyType myType : myClass.getMyTypes())  {

        }
    }

    public void test2() {            
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        Collection<MyType> myTypes = myClass.getMyTypes();
        for (MyType myType : myTypes)  {

        }
    }

    public void test3() {
         MyClass<Long> myClass = new MyClass<Long>();

          for (Long myType : myClass.getMyTs())  {

          }        
     }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use `MyClass` unparameterized in test1 and test2?

Comment: Because I know nothing about type. Java allows this usage.

Comment: But if I have  "public Collection<MyType> getMyTypes()" I'm waiting collection of MyType

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior error: incompatible types
required: MyType
found:    Object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a generic constraint on a class, and then instantiate the class without providing any generic constraint (that is, you leave off the `<>` completely), then you've just stepped into the realm of [**Raw Types**](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic3), where nothing is the same anymore.

According to the [Java Language Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8):

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. **It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.**

According to Angelika Langer's excellent [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ203),

> Methods or constructors of a raw type have the signature that they would have after type erasure. A method or constructor call to a raw type generates an unchecked warning if the erasure changes the argument types.

So by constructing `MyClass` as a raw type (that is, as `MyClass` and not `MyClass<?>`), **you have opted out of generics entirely**, and the return type of `getMyTypes()` is now the raw type `Collection`, and not `Collection<MyType>`.  As a result, you can't use the enhanced `for` syntax with type `MyType`, you'd have to use `Object` instead.

Of course, the better solution is just to use `MyClass<?>` (rather than just `MyClass`) when you mean a `MyClass` of an unknown parameterized type.

Answer (score 2):

I've isolated your problem to a smaller example, which I show below

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestSimple {

    static class MyClass<T> {
        private Collection<String> myTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

        public Collection<String> getMyTypes() {
            return myTypes;
        }
    }

    public void test1() {    
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        for (String myType : myClass.getMyTypes())  {
        }
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that all type information is stripped off unless you specifically tell it otherwise. So my suggestion is to change your declaration:

```
before: MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
after:  MyClass<?> myClass = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

Java is overly harsh on raw types. If you use raw type of generic class, all generic info in the class are ignored, even innocent ones that has nothing to do with type parameters of the class.

```
class A<T> implements List<String>

    Set<Integer> var;
```

If you use raw `A`, then it is treat as

```
class A implements List

    Set var;
```

This harsh treatment isn't necessary; they probably didn't think raw types deserve too much resource, so they took the easy route, erase every generic info from raw types indiscriminately.

Comment: +1 Interesting, I hadn't realized that about raw types. Should probably change `List` to `ArrayList` or another non-interface in the example. Also, it looks like a raw type implementing a generic interface in the same way *does* keep that type information. I wonder what the distinction was behind that decision.

Comment: for `A` to be raw, it has to be a generic class first. if `class A extends B<X>`, `A` is not raw, because A is not even generic.

Answer (score 0):

In `test2` since you haven't parameterized `MyClass`, `getMyTypes()` will effectively return `Collection<Object>`, which is not assignable to `Collection<MyType>`.

Comment: Why should it need to be parameterized for the method `public Collection<MyType> getMyTypes()` to be paramerterized to `MyType`? For example, if you remove `<T>` on `MyType` and remove `Collection<T> getMyTs()` and remove `void test2()` and `void test3()` it compiles just fine.

Comment: @glowcoder yes, but I have "Collection<T> myTs = new ArrayList<T>();" also and it can't be removed

Comment: @Alex see my answer below. The problem still manifests even without those.