# Java generics: wildcard<?> vs type parameter<E>?

Tags: java, generics

I am refreshing my knowledge on Java generics. So I turned to the excellent tutorial from Oracle ... and started to put together a presentation for my coworkers. I came across the section on wildcards in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) that says:

> Consider the following method, printList:
>
> ```
> public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
> ...
> ```
>
> The goal of printList is to print a list of any type, but it fails to achieve that goal — it prints only a list of Object instances; it cannot print `List<Integer>`, `List<String>`, `List<Double>`, and so on, because they are not subtypes of `List<Object>`. To write a generic printList method, use `List<?>`:
>
> ```
> public static void printList(List<?> list) {
> ```

I understand that `List<Object>` will not work; but I changed the code to

```
static <E> void printObjects(List<E> list) {
    for (E e : list) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
...
    List<Object> objects = Arrays.<Object>asList("1", "two");
    printObjects(objects);
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
    printObjects(integers);
```

And guess what; using `List<E>` I can print different types of Lists without any problem.

Long story short: at least the tutorial indicates that one **needs** the wildcard to solve this problem; but as shown, it can be solved this way too. So, what am I missing?!

(side note: tested with Java7; so maybe this was a problem with Java5, Java6; but on the other hand, Oracle seems to do a good job regarding updates of their tutorials)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type parameter vs unbounded wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142009/type-parameter-vs-unbounded-wildcard)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your approach of using a generic method is strictly more powerful than a version with wildcards, so yes, your approach is possible, too. However, the tutorial does *not* state that using a wildcard is the only possible solution, so the tutorial is also correct.

What you gain with the wildcard in comparison to the generic method: You have to write less and the interface is "cleaner" since a non generic method is easier to grasp.

Why the generic method is more powerful than the wildcard method: You give the parameter a name which you can reference. For example, consider a method that removes the first element of a list and adds it to the back of the list. With generic parameters, we can do the following:

```
static <T> boolean rotateOneElement(List<T> l){
    return l.add(l.remove(0));
}
```

with a wildcard, this is not possible since `l.remove(0)` would return `capture-1-of-?`, but `l.add` would require `capture-2-of-?`. I.e., the compiler is not able to deduce that the result of `remove` is the same type that `add` expects. This is contrary to the first example where the compiler can deduce that both is the same type `T`. This code would not compile:

```
static boolean rotateOneElement(List<?> l){
    return l.add(l.remove(0)); //ERROR!
}
```

So, what can you do if you want to have a rotateOneElement method with a wildcard, since it is easier to use than the generic solution? The answer is simple: Let the wildcard method call the  generic one, then it works:

```
// Private implementation
private static <T> boolean rotateOneElementImpl(List<T> l){
    return l.add(l.remove(0));
}

//Public interface
static void rotateOneElement(List<?> l){
     rotateOneElementImpl(l);
}
```

The standard library uses this trick in a number of places. One of them is, IIRC, Collections.java

Comment: @Duncan: Replaced it and clarified the middle part

Comment: The *method itself* is more powerful, but what you do in the method itself and whether you call other private methods are internal implementation details. The *public API* of both are equally powerful.

Comment: @newacct: Right, concerning API, both are equally powerful. I was indeed referring to the implementation.

Answer (score 17):

Technically, there is **no difference** between

```
<E> void printObjects(List<E> list) {
```

and

```
void printList(List<?> list) {
```

---

- When you are declaring a type parameter, and using it only once, it essentially becomes a wildcard parameter.
- On the other hand, if you use it more than once, the difference becomes significant. e.g.

  ```
  <E> void printObjectsExceptOne(List<E> list, E object) {
  ```

  is completely different than

  ```
  void printObjects(List<?> list, Object object) {
  ```

  You might see that first case **enforces** both types to be **same**. While there is no restriction in second case.

---

As a result, if you are going to use a type parameter **only once**, it **does not even make sense to name it**. That is why java architects invented so called wildcard arguments (most probably).

Wildcard parameters avoid unnecessary code bloat and make code more readable. If you need two, you have to fall back to regular syntax for type parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are times when it is used only once but cannot be replaced by a wildcard. For example: 1) if the once it is used is in the return type, 2) if it is a recursively-bounded type parameter e.g. `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Comment: Wildcards are used only when passing a type as an argument. They are out of question when you are talking about type parameters. So first case obviously won't apply here. In second case it **is** used twice.

Comment: You said "When you are declaring a type parameter, and using it only once, it essentially becomes a wildcard parameter." In the case of `public <E> List<E> newList();`, `E` is a type parameter that is only used once.

Comment: Yes I did. And `List<?> newList();` compiles as well.

Comment: Right, but the two mean very different things. So the type parameter cannot be turned into a wildcard.

Comment: E is a type argument in this case, not a type parameter. Only type arguments can be converted to wildcards. Sorry if I have written it otherwise. Will edit it if something's wrong after checking.

Answer (score 9):

Both solutions are effectively the same, it's just that in the second one you are naming the wildcard. This can come handy when you want to use the wildcard several times in the signature, but want to make sure that both refer to the same type:

```
static <E> void printObjects(List<E> list, PrintFormat<E> format) {
```