# saveAll() gets error Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'capture<? extends BaseEntity>'

Tags: java, jpa, generics, spring-data-jpa

Getting a compile time error saying, "Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'capture<? extends BaseEntity>'"

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{
} 

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository<Employee, Integer> extends BaseRepository<Employee, Integer> {

}
```

BaseEntity as:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
...

}
```

Employee class as:

```
 @Entity
 ... 
 public class Employee extends BaseEntity {..}
```

In my class constructor I'm setting BaseRepository<? extends BaseEntity> repository to a concrete implmentation:

```
public class MyClass<T extends BaseEntity> {

BaseRepository<? extends BaseEntity, Integer> repository;

public MyClass(BaseRepository<? extends BaseEntity> repository){
       this.repository = repository
}

 public void doSomething(List<? extends BaseEntity> concreteEntities){
    //...does something
   repository.saveAll(concreteEntities); //throws that compile time error

 }

}
```

I'm passing in EmployeeRepository<Employee, Integer> employeeRepository to the above constructor.

I have looked online and everywhere but I cannot understand why I'm getting this compile time error.

My goal is to save a list of Employee, Contractor, Department etc that all extend BaseEntity (but having a common super class is not a requirement), but saving any list type is needed and I though I could use one class to do it.

I tried replacing T with <? extends BaseEntity> in my BaseRepository definition but no luck.

Additional info:
I have a table for every entity T like Employee table, Department table etc.

Comment: Why are you using wildcards?

Comment: Good question. So at runtime depending on the request I received I want to save either a list of employees or departments or chairs. I have some common logic like getting data from third party with callbacks before I save this data.  So whatever MyClass  does is common to all these entities

Comment: Then why is `MyClass` type-specific?

Comment: If you have a separate instance of `MyClass` for each `T`, you should be using that instead of the wildcards.

Comment: So if I have an instance of MyClass for each request, which can be of any type T, I should be using that for what? I only have one MyClass that gets called for each T.

Comment: Just change `? extends BaseEntity` to `T`.

Comment: That did get rid of the error, but I have no idea why the error happened and how changing the <? extends BaseEntity> to T fixed it.  It seems like I don't really need BaseEntity here, but I'm confused as to when it would have been needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`? extends BaseEntity` means "some specific, unknown subtype of `BaseEntity`". You can't pass it to the repository because as far as the compiler is concerned, `repository` might be a `BaseRepository<Employee, Integer>`, while `concreteEntities` might be a `List<Contractor>`. The solution is to use your type parameter `T` instead:

```
public class MyClass<T extends BaseEntity> {

    BaseRepository<T, Integer> repository;
    
    public MyClass(BaseRepository<T> repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void doSomething(List<T> concreteEntities){
        //...does something
        repository.saveAll(concreteEntities);
    }
}
```

This ensures that no matter which subtype `T` represents, it's the same type across all uses for this instance.

See also:
[What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)
[Java generics: wildcard<?> vs type parameter<E>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860582/java-generics-wildcard-vs-type-parametere)