# Confusion about Generic type and Lists

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am learning about generics and Lists in C# but I am very confused with the syntax and the use of the two topics. I have read the MSDN but I am even more confused after reading it.

I am confused how sometimes you can have `public T variable name;` <-- variable of type `T`???

Then you can somehow have `List<T>` or `List<double>` `List<int>` <- why do we need the `<>` all of a sudden and what is this new class called List? If `T` is a new type different from int or `double` or `string` then what values does this new type hold? Why can we put `<double>`? Are these 2 different concepts? (the `List<T>` and `List<double>`) Now they are even using arrays with type `T`....**This type `T` and `List` are the 2 things really confusing me.** What is the purpose/use of `List` and how is it different from `<T>`?

Comment: Seems like you are missing the basics before generics and lists

Comment: I'll suggest you to read about `ArrayList` then find out the problems with arraylist which will make you understand what is `List<T>`

Comment: This may help [Benefits of generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee.aspx)

Comment: I already know that if you have some algorithm or computation being performed on array of type int and now you want to do the exact same thing on an array of type string then you have to re-type the code but this generic type allows your compiler to take care of that so you can write just 1 block of code of a non-specific type. However, I don't get how to "use" this generic type or what List is and if T is this generic type or LIst<> is this generic type....Confused how to use/create this generic type.

Comment: I believe it's a completely honest question and my best answer is for you to read some book about c#; or try a pluralsight video.
If you're unfamiliar with object oriented programming (oop) read something about it first; Bear in mind thatProgramming is not something you learn in 24 hours

Comment: @HarrisCalvin I have provided you with a link to different topic in my answer, where you probably can find the answer for your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is simply a placeholder for a type. So for example:

```
public void PrintType<T>(T source)
{
    Console.WriteLine(source.GetType());
}

int number = 23;
string text = "Hello";

PrintType(number);
PrintType(text);
```

Here we have a generic function that takes in a `T source` parameter. The type of that parameter could be anything, thus we use `T` to flag that. You could use any letter, but `T` seems most often used.

When you have a generic list `List<int>` for example, you are declaring the type that the list will hold, in this case `integers`. This is why you need the `<>`, it's where you specify the type.

`List<>` doesn't create a generic type, it is a collection object that can store objects of type `T` (assuming you declare the list as `List<T>` e.g. `List<int>`, `List<string>`, etc). Under the hood, `List<>` does use an array, but don't worry too much about the details.

EDIT:

For reference, here is some simplified, partial, code for `List<>` which I obtained using [`dotPeek`](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

```
public class List<T>
{
    private static readonly T[] _emptyArray = new T[0];
    private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;
    private T[] _items;
    private int _size;
    private int _version;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
      if (this._size == this._items.Length)
        this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);

      this._items[this._size++] = item;
    }

    private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
    {
      if (this._items.Length >= min)
        return;
      int num = this._items.Length == 0 ? 4 : this._items.Length * 2;
      if (num < min)
        num = min;
      this.Capacity = num;
    }

    public int Capacity
    {
      [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")] get
      {
        return this._items.Length;
      }
      set
      {
        if (value < this._size)
          ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
        if (value == this._items.Length)
          return;
        if (value > 0)
        {
          T[] objArray = new T[value];
          if (this._size > 0)
            Array.Copy((Array) this._items, 0, (Array) objArray, 0, this._size);
          this._items = objArray;
        }
        else
          this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
      }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `List<>` is a wrapper class that uses an array, in this case a generic array. I highly recommend getting dotPeek, or another similar tool, and looking at things like `List<>`, so you can get a better understanding of how they work.

Comment: so List is another type of data holding method? Like arrays? Or is List the way you define this generic type? It seems like T is just a place holder but then is List how you create this generic type? Why do you have a <T> after PrintType?

Comment: @HarrisCalvin - List is same as an array but it can dynamically re-size itself.`<T>` is added to register the generic Type in the method. This `T` can in fact be anything like `PrintType<Dinosaur>(Dinosaur source)`. Since C# doesn't know the type `Dinosaur`, we register it as `<Dinosaur>`

Comment: @Krishna ahhh now THAT is the answer I was trying to find. I wish you put that in code so I can accept it as answer because that was my big confusion.

Comment: One last quesion: Can I do T varibla= names? where names is a variable of type string.

Comment: No, but you can do this `var varibla = names`. `var` is a C# 3.0 keyword that says "Set the variable `varibla` to `names`, but I don't know (or care) what the type of `names` is (so you don't bother with `string varibla = names`). At run-time, `varibla` will be defined as a string, if `names` is a string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well `T` could be pretty much any type, that is why it is called `T`ype. For example if you need a `List` with strong typing of given type for example:

You have created your own type called `Car`, then you want to have a `List` filled only with `Cars` then you use:

`List<Car> carsList = new List<Car>();`

, if you would use simple List, you could put anything in there.

But you can also use  in method definitions and even Interfaces and so on.

```
privat void GenericMethod<T>(T var)
{
   //your code
}
```

So in general the type inside `<T>` informs you of... type used by method or variable.

You could also find some more useful information here:

[Another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231973/difference-between-list-list-listt-liste-and-listobject)

By visiting this topic, you should find answers for your questions, as it is clearly explained there.

Comment: Well not sure what you really want, but you can ask for the difference between tchem, as both `List` and `T` are different things, even if `T` can be a `List`, and `List` can store `T` objects. `List` is a rawtype and `T` is generic.