# Are List<?> and List same?

Tags: java

Are these two code snippets are totally same? Is there any difference?

```
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
for (Object elem: list)
    System.out.print(elem + " ");
}


public static void printList(List list) {
for (Object elem: list)
    System.out.print(elem + " ");
}
```

Comment: The only difference is that in method receiving `List<?>` you cannot add elements in the list while the other method allows it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Nothing stopping you from adding items to `List<?>`. It's just using generics, while the other list isn't.

Comment: @t0m You'll want to test that.

Comment: @t0mppa I recommend you to test it in code

Comment: @t0mppa "Nothing stopping you from adding items to `List<?>.`" nothing beside compiler, who doesn't know type of elements in the list so just to be safe prevents you from adding anything to list (except `null`). You can add elements to this list, but not via `List<?>` reference (you can try casting it to `List<SomeType>` for example).

Comment: You can check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231973/difference-between-list-list-listt-liste-and-listobject. It addresses your question clearly.

Comment: It's not only about not being able to add to the List, it's about not being able to use any method that uses the generic type variable as a parameter with anything other than null.

Comment: perhaps you'll find this explanation a bit easier 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal?rq=1

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis & @LuiggiMenodza: Ah, you learn something new every day. Never used a `List<?>`, so mistakenly thought it works the same. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: See http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ303

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are right, adding was just example. It could be also removing, setting or any other method using generic type. I just needed one of many scenarios that could show why it is not possible.