# Difference between List<?> and List<T> .

Tags: list, wildcard, type-parameter

Can anyone please give me answer. Since in both the cases I can pass anything, then what is the difference between two.

Comment: This question has already answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231973/difference-between-list-list-listt-liste-and-listobject

Comment: Never used the `?` before, but I know you can put restrictions on what `<T>` is.  Can you do the same for `?`