# How to create list with unknown object in java

Tags: java, list, class, object, generics

I speak Spanish, use the translator to ask this question, Sorry for the spelling.

Also, do not be like asking exactly what I want to do.

I want to create a list of an object passing through parameter.

```
public void createListUnknown(? Class myClass?  or  ? Object myObject?) {

    List<myClass> my_list;

       //or

    List<myObject> my_list;


}
```

example use:

```
public class Model{
    public String name;
    public String age;
}
```

as it should be?

```
createListUnknown(?? MyModel ??)
```

Basically I want to create a list with an object that comes parameter to a function

An example where you want to apply is the following:

```
    //final GsonModelUsuariosLoginGet gsonModelUsuariosLoginGet
//= gson.fromJson(responseData, GsonModelUsuariosLoginGet.class);
return gson.fromJson(responseData, httpObject.getObjectGet().getClass());
```

and

```
Object aClass = httpObject.getObjectGet().getClass();

List< httpObject.getObjectGetClass() > aClasses;

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<aClass>>(){}.getType();
final List<GsonModelArticulos> articulos = gson.fromJson(responseData, collectionType);
```

Comment: You edited your question to add an exemple but you don't show where you want to use your method.

Comment: Thanks, First of all thanks. probe your code and tell me the following message: "list is not abstract can be instantiated."

this also fails : return new List<T>() = new ArrayList<T>();

Comment: This will suit your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231973/difference-between-list-list-listt-liste-and-listobject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**create list**

```
public <T> List<T> makeList(Class<T> type) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
```

**get type list**

Using the [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) interface.

```
private <T> Type getType(Class<T> type) {
        Type typeOfObjectsListNew = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.getType();
        return typeOfObjectsListNew;
    }
```