# Please explain this for me please? private List<> name(List<> model, String name) in java

Tags: java, android

Please explain this for me please?  private List<> name(List<> model, String name)

Comment: Read the documentation. Also, that doesn't compile.

Comment: what is the error you are getting an what is the line of code that is getting the error? also you evaluate `not equal` as `!=` in java.

Comment: @user3299379 `<>` does not mean `not equal` in this context - it refers to [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

Comment: That does not look like valid Java code. There should be some names between the `<>`. Make sure you copy it exactly as it as.

Comment: you can read about the List [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6232041/7676637)

Comment: @Heena Khan, the Tutorial would be the place to start, then the Javadocs and JLS.

Answer (score 0):

**private List<> name(List<> model, String name)** is not a correct java code.

But in the idea you has a private method (function)  called **name** that return a **List**.
That function has 2 parameters : 1 list called **model** and 1 String call **name**.

Your  problem : List of what ??? 
**List** if if the return of your function is a array of String. 
Same problem with model, List of what ??