# What does <?> stand for in Java?

Tags: java, raw-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics)

In Eclipse, I am given warnings for using 'rawtypes' and one of it's fixes is to add `<?>`. For example:

```
    Class parameter = String.class;
    //Eclipse would suggest a fix by converting to the following:
    Class<?> parameter = String.class;
```

What does this `<?>` actually mean?

Comment: If you want go deeper with generics, see [effective chapter 5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf)

Comment: IMHO, It stands for confusion. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Raw types refer to using a generic type without specifying a type parameter. For example, List is a raw type, while List<String> is a parameterized type

See this document for more info: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=224

Comment: @Jason what version of the answer are you looking at?

Answer (score 5):

`Class<?>` should be interpreted as a `Class` of something, but the something isn't known or cared about.

It's the use of Java generic types. `Class` in Java 5 or greater is a parameterized type, so the compiler expects a type parameter. `Class<String>` would work in the specific context of your code, but again, in many cases you don't care about the actual type parameter, so you can just use `Class<?>` which is telling the compiler that you know `Class` expects a type parameter, but you don't care what the parameter is.

Answer (score 1):

This is way beyond the scope of this site, but here are some links:

- [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)
- [Sun Java Tutorial / Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)
- [Java Generics and Collections
  (Book)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754)

Answer (score 1):

The warning means that `List` expects the type of the items but you didn't specify one. Since the compiler can't tell whether you made a mistake or forgot something, it gives the warning.

There are several solutions: If you really don't care what's in the list, use `<?>`. It means "can be anything, I don't care."

If you probably care but this is old legacy code and you don't want to fix it, tell Eclipse to ignore it with the `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` and/or `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` if you're casting.

The best solution is to figure out the correct type and use that. This way, the compiler can help you catch more typos at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Class is a generic type since Java 5 (years ago).

Read [the Java tutorial about generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because  represents a generic wildcard, as in the type specified between the brackets could be any reference type. Java prefers strong typing and is issuing you a warning to convince you to specify a concrete type as the type specifier.

For example:

```
Class<String> parameter = String.class;
```