# List vs List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

Why do we lose type safety when using `List` and not while using `List<Object>`? Aren't they basically the same thing?

**EDIT**: I found that the following gives a compilation error

```
public class TestClass
{
    static void func(List<Object> o, Object s){
        o.add(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        func(new ArrayList<String>(), new Integer(1));
    }
}
```

whereas this doesn't

```
public class TestClass
{
    static void func(List o, Object s){
        o.add(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        func(new ArrayList<String>(), new Integer(1));
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: The direct answer to why does the second one compile is so that code written before java 5 can be compiled by 5 and later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do we lose type safety when using `List` and not while using `List<Object>`? Aren't they basically the same thing?

No they are not the same thing.

If you are providing an API,

```
class API {
  static List<Object> getList() { ... }
  static void modifyList(List<Object> l) { ... }
}
```

and a client uses it improperly

```
List<Integer> list = API.getList();
API.modifyList(list);
for (Integer i : list) { ... }  // Invalid
```

then when your API specifies `List<Object>` they get a compile-time error, but they don't when `API.getList()` returns a `List` and `API.modifyList(list)` takes a `List` without generic type parameters.

EDIT:

In comments you mentioned changing

```
void func(List<Object> s, Object c) { s.add(c); }
```

to

```
void func(List s, Object c) { s.add(c); }
```

so that

```
func(new List<String>(), "");
```

would work.

That is violating type safety.  The type-safe way to do this is

```
<T> void func(List<? super T> s, T c) { s.add(c); }
```

which is basically saying that `func` is a parameterized function that takes a `List` whose type can be any super class of T, and a value of type T, and adds the value to the list.

Comment: Yes, I found a similar case. The program doesn't compile when i have this:
`func(List<Object> s, Object c){ s.add(c)}` and call  `func(new ArrayList<String>(), new Integer(1));`.

It compiles when I change the method to `func(List s, Object o)` and call it again in the same way

Comment: Without generic type, the for loop would not compile as well.

Comment: @Varun, a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>` because `myList.add(Boolean.FALSE)` is valid when `myList` is a `List<Object>` but not when it is a `List<String>`.  Maybe your function should be `<T> void func(List<? super T> s, T c) { s.add(c); }`

Comment: "The type-safe way to do this is..." It is sufficient to say `<T> void func(List<T> s, T c) { s.add(c); }`

Comment: @user102008, true.  That is not as general though.  You cannot then do `List<Object> heterogeneousList = ...; func(heterogeneousList, "foo");` because the `"foo"` makes `T` bind to `String` at that call-site, but the `hetergeneousList` has a type of `List<Object>` which is not a `List<T>`.  If I was trying to be as general as possible though, I should've probably used a `Collection` instead of a `List`.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Yes you can. Try it.

Comment: @user102008, You're right.  The `<T>` in your signature binds to the type-bottom of (`String`, `Object`) which is (`Object`), but in my signature `<T>` binds to `String`.  I was mistakenly assuming it would fail because I was assuming `<T>` would be `String` in both cases.

Answer (score 8):

`List` is a list of *some type you don't know*. It could be a `List<String>`, `List<Integer>`, etc.
It's effectively equivalent to `List<?>`, or `List<? extends Object>`, except that it *doesn't* document that fact. It's only supported for backwards compatibility.

`List<Object>` is a **list of Objects**. *Any* object of *any* type can be put inside it, contrary to a `List<String>`, for example, which only accepts strings.

So no, they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

A `List<Object>` isn't really any more typesafe than a `List`. However, the `Object` in the code does imply intent. When someone else looks at it later, they can see that you purposefully chose `Object` as the type, rather than wondering if you just forgot to put a type or are storing something else and typecasting it elsewhere.

Since code gets read more than it gets written, hints at the intent of the code can be very valuable later on.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have a compiler warning when you use `List` instead of `List<Object>` is that when you have a `List` the compiler doesn't know what type of List it is, so while you could treat it as a  `List<Object>`, the compiler can't ensure that at some other point in the code it wasn't set to reference a `List<String>` and the type safety of the Generics cannot be checked. That is really the compiler warning here - it is saying it can't help ensure the type safety of the generics, and it won't happen at runtime either (until at some later point there is an actual cast in the code).

Answer (score 0):

For purposes here, you could say they're the same thing. But presumably you almost never actually fill a `List` with pure instance of `Object`. They're `String`s or something. In this example, `List<Object>` is technically using generics but not really taking any advantage of it. So, it loses the compile-time type checking of generics.

Answer (score 0):

Type Erasure is one answer and the backward compatibility to pre Java 1.5 and tighter type check in case of first one.

Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:

Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.