# Why were generics introduced for the Collection classes?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Was type safety the only reason to introduce generics for the `java.util.Collection` classes, so the addition of heterogeneous elements in a `Collection` is prevented? Or have there been other reasons too?

Comment: Why are you asking? Is it just of curiosity or there is some other reason too?

Comment: Because it's redundant to write `List` for `Integer`, then `List` for `String`, then for `Double`, then for......

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov just curiosity

Comment: @MarounMaroun no I don't think so,they wrote it for object,so redundancy is not the reason

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Generics in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)

Comment: Because the type system was incomplete without it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that the reason is that most use-cases require a collection of just one class, or one class and its subclasses.  For those use-cases, it is *convenient* to have a type-safe collection where you don't need to typecast the keys / values / entries extracted from the respective collections.

Use-cases where you genuinely need a "collection of any object" are unusual.  But these use-cases are supported by using a `?` as the collection type parameter; e.g.

```
    List<Object> listOfAnything = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

Clearly, generics do not prevent heterogeneous collections.  But if you want homogeneous collections, generics allow you to do this conveniently and with type-safety.

Comment: True ..........................

Answer (score 1):

Generics were introduced to the Java language to increase the type safety.

Say you have a list of items, to which you are only adding instances of class A:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
list.add(new A());
list.add(new A());
...
```

When you want to use some of the objects you entered the list, you do something like:

```
A a1 = (A) list.get(0);
A a2 = (A) list.get(1);
...
```

However, nothing prevents anyone from doing the following:

```
list.add(new NonA());
```

which will result in you getting a ClassCastException in your code. This is because the types are being checked in run time not in compilation time.

Enter generics, which allow you to do the following:

```
List<A> list = new LinkedList<A>();
list.add(new A());
list.add(new A());
...
```

And now, if anyone tries the following:

```
list.add(new NonA());
```

They will get a compilation error, thus preventing this error.