# where we need to declare class<T> type of class declaration

Tags: java, class

What does class mean. when we required this kind of classes.
e.g.

```
class SimpleCounter<T> { /*...*/ }

SimpleCounter<Double> doubleCounter = new SimpleCounter<Double>();
```

Comment: Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: [What are Generics in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7815528)

Answer (score 3):

See From [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

> A generic class is defined with the following format:
>
> `class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }`
> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.
>
> To update the Box class to use generics, you create a generic type declaration by changing the code "`public class Box`" to "public class Box<T>". This introduces the type variable, T, that can be used anywhere inside the class.
>
> With this change, the Box class becomes:
>
> ```
> /**
>     * Generic version of the Box class.
>     * @param <T> the type of the value being boxed
>     */
> public class Box<T> {
>     // T stands for "Type"
>     private T t;
>
>     public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
>     public T get() { return t; }
> }
> ```