# How to make arrayList read Strings only but not int?

Tags: java

> Write a method called countWords that accepts an ArrayList of String as argument and
>   prints out the number of words (i.e. Strings) that start with ―A‖ or ―a‖ and prints all words longer than 5 characters on one line.

My solution is like

```
int count=0;
    String[] st=null;

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("please input something");

while(input.hasNext()) {
        String st1=input.next();
        array.add(st1);

    }


    for(int i=0; i<array.size();i++) {
        if(array.get(i).startsWith("a")||array.get(i).startsWith("A")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
        for(int j=0; j<array.size(); j++) {
            if(array.get(j).length()>5) 
                st[j]=array.get(j);

        }

        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println(st);
}
```

but there will be no end for typing in Strings

Comment: `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)

Comment: What have you already done?

Comment: The statement starts by "Write a method called countWords that accepts an ArrayList of String as argument". You haven't written any such method.

Comment: If you just press enter key with no input, the input loop will end

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of `st`? You can print a list, and you're never asked for an array

Comment: On another note you sure you mean `array.get(i).startsWith("a")&array.get(i).startsWith("A")`? (1) It's not possible for a word to start with both a lower and upper case `a`. (2) It's uncommon to use the bitwise & with booleans.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake, I mean || actually.

Answer (score 0):

As the last line of your question said

**`but there will be no end for typing in Strings`**

Well That is because you did not provided any way to end the while loop.

```
while(input.hasNext())
```

Will run forever and ever waiting for next user input. You have to `break` the while loop once the inputting is done.

**AFTERWARDS**

`As the question said` **`"prints out the number of words that start with A or a and prints all words longer than 5 characters on one line."`**

For this you can loop through the `ArrayList` and check for

```
if(array.get(i).startsWith("A") || array.get(i).startsWith("a")) count++;

if(array.get(i).length()>5) System.out.print(array.get(i)+" ");
```

and print the number of A or a Occurrence after the loop

```
System.out.println("\n Number of word with A or a:"+count);
```

Here is a working implementation of your code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count=0;
    String[] st=null;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("please input something");
    //System.out.println(input.hasNext());
while(input.hasNext()) {
        String st1=input.next();
        //System.out.println((int) st1.charAt(0));
        if(st1.equals("exit")) break;
        array.add(st1);

    }


    for(int i=0; i<array.size();i++) {
        if(array.get(i).startsWith("A") || array.get(i).startsWith("a")){
            count++;
        }
        if(array.get(i).length()>5) {
            System.out.print(array.get(i)+" ");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\nNumber of word with A or a:"+count);
}
```

**`to end the loop you have to type exit.`**

Comment: Thank you so so so so much, I have tried on eclipse, that is really helpful for a rookie like me!

Comment: you should support everyone else too if your problem is solved and you are satisfied you must mark question as solved and vote the answer up :) it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem..

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args){
        // Sample String sentence 
        String sentence = "This is the sentence with 5 words starting with 
             all like allwords alltogether also Allnotout allother and allofus.";

        // Splitting above sentence to get each word separately and storing them into List
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(sentence.split("\\s+"));
         // calling a method named countWord() as per your assignment question.
        Test.countWords(strings);
    }


    // implementing that method
    static void countWords(List<String> input){
        long count = input.stream().filter(word -> word.startsWith("all") || word.startsWith("All")).count();
        System.out.print("Total words starting with all/All are : "+ count +"\t");
        input.stream().filter(word -> word.length() > 5).forEach( word -> System.out.print(word + "\t"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply

Comment: Most welcome..!! I think you already found your solution.. but I would recommend If you are on Java 8, you must try this.. you will learn a lot. !! So many complex things, in so simple way..!! :)

Comment: You're supposed to print all words words longer than 5 and the number of words that starts with "all" or "All", your code doesn't do that at all.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for raising hand.. see edit, did I still miss anything??