# Is it possible to override the argument type of an overridden method?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Can someone help me with the code below?

I have 2 classes `Controller1` and `Controller2` implementing the interface Controllers as below:

```
package com.controllers
public interface Controllers{
    public void method1(*****);
}
------------------------------
package com.controllers
public class Controller1{
    public void method1(com.model1.Module1 module);
}
------------------------------
package com.controllers
public class Controller2{
    public void method1(com.model2.Module1 module);
}
------------------------------
```

I have 2 packages which have the same classes (both classes have same methods as well) as below

```
package com.model1
public class Module1{

}
------------------------
package com.model1
public class Module2{

}
-----------------------
package com.model2
public class Module1{

}
------------------------
package com.model2
public class Module2{

}
```

I am using a Factory class to get the instance of either `Controller1` or `Controller2` at the runtime, so the argument types for `method1` in the inherited classes will vary. But I am unable to so, as a method signature cannot be overridden.

Can someone suggest me with an alternative? Thanks...

Comment: If the number of parameters would be the same then you can use Generics.

Comment: Number of parameters will be same. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Generics can't be explained in a single answer. For starters, visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 packages which have the same classes(both classes have same methods as well)

Why you didn't created common parent interface for Module1, Module2 then?

It will be looks like

```
package com.model1
public class Module1 implements Model {

}
------------------------
package com.model1
public class Module2 implements Model{

}
-----------------------
package com.model2
public class Module1 implements Model{

}
------------------------
package com.model2
public class Module2 implements Model{

}
```

And

```
package com.controllers
public interface Controllers{
    public void method1(Model model);
}
```

But may be I missed something in your question

Comment: Module1 and Module2 have different methods. Creating a single interface is not a good idea I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, if you don't want to use Module1 or Module2 methods you can create an empty interface with name Method and that's will be a solution. If you want use their methods you can do the same and add something like that (read about reflection in Java)

```
package com.controllers
public interface Controllers{
    public void method1(Model model) {
        if (model instanceof com.model1.Module1) {
            com.model1.Module1 module = (com.model1.Module1) model;
            ...
        } else if (model instanceof com.model2.Module1) {
            com.model2.Module1 module = (com.model2.Module1) model;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put some generics in a use?

like this:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object module = new Random().nextBoolean()? new Module2(): new Module1();
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        Controllers produce1 = factory.produce(module.getClass());
        produce1.method1(module);

    }
}

class Factory {

    Controllers produce(Class<?> clz) {
        if (Module1.class.equals(clz)) return new Controller1();
        if (Module2.class.equals(clz)) return new Controller2();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

}

interface Controllers<T> {
    void method1(T t);
}

class Controller1 implements Controllers<Module1> {

    public void method1(Module1 integer) {
        System.out.println("in 1!");
    }
}

class Controller2 implements Controllers<Module2> {

    public void method1(Module2 module) {
        System.out.println("in 2!");
    }
}


class Module1 {

}

class Module2 {

}
```

Comment: Module1 and Module2 have different methods. So, its better to create separate interface for each Module from all the packages(If it is that so, I will have to create 9 interfaces).

Comment: Also, the object produce1 will be initialized dynamically. In this case, how do I declare the reference variable? Thanks

Comment: updated my example, you need to change parameter of method `produce(Class<?> clz)` and you can do whatever you want in runtime.