# How to access attributes from an object inside a list?

Tags: java, collections

Well I have a Collection of Books that I need to use to write methods from an Interface. But I don`t know how to access the attributes or methods from the object inside this collection.

I tried to implement like this but its says "type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Book".

```
public class MyCozyLibrary implements SmallLibrary {

private Collection allBooks;

@Override
public Book getBook(BookTag tag) {
    for (Book book : allBooks) {
        if (tag == book.getTag()) {
            return book;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `private Collection<Book> allBooks;` instead.

Have a look at [What are Generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)

Comment: I don`t know if I can change this part of the code, because I have the class with the sectors that I need to write the code. If there is any other way I`ll be glad.