# Usage of parameters inside <> in a class

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in Java and Android development. I stumbled upon the super class AsyncTask which its usage might look like this:

```
private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private static final String TAG = "DownloadData";
...
}
```

I don't understand the usage of the parameters inside the <>. These are not related to the constructor as I checked this superclass and its default constructor doesn't accept any parameters. So what is the usage of paramteres inside <> of a class?

PLEASE NOTE: I'm not asking about those specific three parameters, I know what they stand for, I'm just asking about general use of this syntax.
Also, does this syntax have a name, so I can research this further?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What are generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/generics/complete-java-generics-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'm marking as duplicate