# What does a generic in front of a method mean?

Tags: java, function, generics

I found a function that basically looks like this:

```
<R> MyClass<R> functionName(){}
```

I have no Idea what the `<R>` right in front means and I didn't really find anything by googling it. I know what generics are, I just dont know what they do in that specific spot.

Comment: Remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good hint. So that means I can decide on the generic Type when executing the method and don't have to do it when creating my class?

Comment: Generic classes and generic methods are different beasts. Sometimes you just need a generic parameter in the method, and for static methods for example you have no choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first  is a kind of declaring that functionName will use generics, generally we use R to represent "return", which means this function will return an instance of MyClass which manipulates R objects.

For better understanding, this is a way to call functionName if it was static:

```
public class AClass{

   class MyClass<TYPE>{}

   static <R> MyClass<R> functionName(){return null;}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      AClass.<String>functionName();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It will let you write methods that can act as general purpose helper methods for any type.

Here is an example of reversing the contents of a `List` implementation and return it in an `ArrayList`.

```
        List<String> liststr = new ArrayList<>(List.of("A","B","C"));
        List<String> reversed = reverse(liststr);
        System.out.println(reversed);

        List<Integer> listint = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,4));
        List<Integer> reverseint = reverse(listint);
        System.out.println(reverseint);
```

And here is the method.

```
    public static <T>  List<T> reverse(ArrayList<T> list) {
        List<T> rev = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            rev.add(list.get(i));
        }
        return rev;
    }
```

This could have been done a different way but it would require `casting` of the return value and might also generate a `runtime` `cast exception`.

As in all generic methods and classes, type conflicts will be resolved at `compile time` and not at `runtime`.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the R is a variable, which is assigned when the method is executed and can be assigned any class.
This might help: [What are Generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)