# What am I accomplishing using generics?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have the following code block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] test = new Integer[100];
    comparableTest(test);
    genericsTest(test);
}

private static void comparableTest(Comparable[] c) {

}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void genericsTest(E[] e) { }
```

What exactly am I accomplishing using the generics? These both have no compile errors. I can still use the compareTo method. So what am I gaining using `E extends Comparable<E>` instead of just using `Comparable`?

The context for this question is that I am making sorting algorithms use the `E extends Comparable<E>` instead of `Comparable`.

Comment: Considering you are doing nothing, you are accomplishing nothing.

Comment: I've edited my post with some context of use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation

- Without the generics you could get a class that is not comparable to itself but to other things. Like an `A implements Comparable<B>`, this is unusual but possible.
- Also, you just lose type safety on the `compareTo`, as it then falls back to accepting `Object`s. So you could accidentally make a mistake, passing the wrong thing and Java can not help you and prevent it.

For real, there is no reason why you should ever consider using **raw types** (dropping the generics) if you are not forced to develop for earlier than Java 5.

---

### Example

An example, considering your snippet, you pass `Integer[]` into it. An `Integer` can not be compared to `Dog`s. So if you accidentally do something stupid like:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
if (c[0].compareTo(dog) == 0) { ... }
```

This will actually compile with the variant that takes `Comparable[]`, but crash on runtime when you execute it. The other variant is able to detect this bug at compile-time and generally help you spot your mistake much earlier, which is good.

This example may look contrived but stuff like that can happen really quick.

---

### Note

You might want to consider renaming your `c` to something that helps readability. Someone reading a `c` might not know what it represents in your case, maybe it stands for a character, maybe a car.

In general, try to avoid abbreviating. What about `comparables`, `elements` or `items`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a perfect reason. In regards to your note, the sample code was made for the sake of the question. Here's the full context: https://github.com/Arham4/sorting-algorithms-analysis