# What does K k; and V v; mean in this Java Method in the Map.Class?

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, types

I'm new to Java and am looking at the forEach method in the Map.class in Java... here is an excerpt of that method:

```
default void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entrySet()) {
        K k;
        V v;
        //more code follows...
```

My question is... what is going on with K k; and V v;?  The method goes on the use k and v as local variables so I'm guessing the K k; and V v; lines are assigning the arguments to local variables... but if that's true why doesn't this syntax need a type?  Thank you in advance for the help.

I didn't try anything or expect anything... just want to better understand what this code is doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)

Comment: The types are there. They are `K` and `V`. The term you should be looking for is "generics"

Comment: <rant>Wouldn't it be nice if the "generics" (ie, type parameter) naming convention were NOT from the 1970's? `KeyType` and `ValueType` would be so much more intuitive than`K` and `V`.</rant>

Comment: Think `Integer i` or `String s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map<K, V>` is a *parameterised type*, which means that it represents a whole family of different types, such as

- `Map<String, Integer>` - a `Map` where the keys are `String`s and the values are `Integer`s
- `Map<Integer, LocalDate>` - a `Map` where the keys are `Integer`s and the values are `LocalDate`s

and so on.  But there's a kind of sameness about all these types - they're all a `Map` where the keys have some type and the values have some other type.

Now the processing inside the `Map` is going to be much the same, regardless of the type of its keys or the type of its values.  So none of the code inside `Map.class` should specify what those types are.  Instead, it uses `K` to represent whatever type the keys will be, and `V` to represent whatever type the values will be.  These letters are called *type parameters*, and they are used in `Map.class` as a way to refer to the types that will be used in the `Map`.

For example, if you have a `Map<String, Integer>`, then `K` means `String` and `V` means `Integer`.  If you have a `Map` with different key type and value type, then `K` and `V` will mean something else.

In the method that you've shown in your question, `k` is a local variable of the type represented by `K` and `v` is a local variable of the type represented by `V`.  Again, if you have a `Map<String, Integer>`, `k` is effectively a `String` variable, and `v` is an `Integer` variable.  But these could actually be any types at all.

Where you've written `//more code follows...` the code in question will just be pulling a key and value out of the `Map`, pointing the variables `k` and `v` at them, and then applying the `BiConsumer` called `action` to them.

Answer (score 0):

Even when understanding what are generics this code alone is not really clear.

Therefore you need to take a look at the top of the `Map` interface declaration

```
public interface Map<K,V>
```

Read also:

- [Lesson: Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)