# java public class name<Item>

Tags: java

I am new to Java and this type of expression.

```
public class name<Item>
```

What is the point of `Item` here? What will happen if I remove this?

Comment: You should have a look at what are generics in Java.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java Look at Generic types in Java.

Comment: After your edit, your code no longer has `<Item>` and the question is nonsensical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics)

Answer (score 6):

That's a declaration of a generic class. `Item` is the parametric name of a type that is filled in when an instance of the class is declared (or possibly when the class is subclassed). For more information, see the [Java tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

As to what will happen if you remove it, that depends on what the body of the `name` class is. However, the usual thing that happens is that you need to replace all occurrences of `Item` in the definition of `name` with `Object`. In client code, you will occasionally need to use casts to get things to compile, and you will lose type safety.

Answer (score 2):

It's to define a Generic Type that will be acceptable to the class.

The easiest example to understand is `List`

If you create one, you can specify what type of elements you want that list to contain.

For example, if you want a list that contains only String objects, you can define it like this:

```
List<String> myStringList;
```

When you do this, you can be sure that only *Strings* will be added to your list. That is `Type safety`.

You can't even assign to your list another list of a subtype with this type safety, here's an example:

```
List<Number> myNumberList;
List<Integer> myIntegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myNumberList = myIntegerList;
```

If you try that you get this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Integer>` to `List<Number>`

But there are things to be done in these situations, you could make the previous scenario work by changing the List type defiinition like this:

```
List<? extends Number> myNumberList;
List<Integer> myIntegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myNumberList = myIntegerList;
```

That works just fine.

- **See also**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/