# In Java what does <T> before a method signature mean?

Tags: java, static, void

I was wondering what `static <T>` means in this context? or is it `<T> void`?

I know what static and void both mean but I'm not sure what `<T>` means here

```
 static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Comment: It is generic method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html. In short `T`  represents type which will be inferred based on what parameters you will pass to method, which lets you pass `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` or others.

Comment: Ok so what does <? super T> mean? I thought super is used to call the parent's constructor before calling the current class's?

Comment: You should read tutorial about generics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html first. It is all explained there. If you will have problems with some part of tutorial then ask question and explain what confuses you.

Comment: @Aceboy1993 `super` has many meanings in different contexts.  Here is `? super T` any type to which `T` can be assigned. e.g. `Number n = new Integer(1);` `T` is `Integer` and `? super T` in this case is `Number`

Comment: or try this already answered related SO questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<T>` means that there is a generic `T` being used in this declaration.  This has two impacts;

- The `T` in the first type of the first argument must match the type in the second argument. (And `? super T` means it must be a super class or interface of `T`)  Without the use of a generic, there is no way to do this.
- The type can be given explicitly with a statement like `Collections.<Integer>sort(list, myComparator);`