# What does <> mean in a classname?

Tags: java, android

My question is what does this:
`<RecentActivity, RecentActivityController>`

mean in this code:
`public class RecentActivity extends AbstractActionActivity<RecentActivity, RecentActivityController>`

Actually I want know the concept of the < and > operators.
Clould someone give references to learn about them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as generics and here AbstractActionActivity is a generic class which accepts two parameters. For example, from the oracle tutorials:

```
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

> As you can see, all occurrences of Object are replaced by T. A type
>   variable can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class type,
>   any interface type, any array type, or even another type variable.

You can learn further [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)