# JavaFX Spinner.getValue()

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am working on a JavaFX form. The form is supposed to take the Value and add it to a data base. Whenever I try to get the value by `.getValue` it creates an error

```
Incompatible Types: Object cannot be converted to Int
```

Here is the FXML Code:

```
<Spinner fx:id="spinner" layoutX="494.0" layoutY="528.0" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0">
    <valueFactory>
       <SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory min="0" max="30" initialValue="20" amountToStepBy="1"/>
    </valueFactory>
</Spinner>
```

Java Code:

```
 Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner) spinner;
        int value = mySpinner.getValue;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: **Don't** ever use `raw types`. Use something like this instead `Spinner<Integer> mySpinner = (Spinner<Integer>) spinner;`  then it should work

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just posting the comment as an answer. To resolve this question:

**Don't** ever use `raw types`. Use something like this instead:

```
Spinner<Integer> mySpinner = (Spinner<Integer>) spinner;
```

Comment: There shouldn't really be a need for the cast, either.

Comment: @James_D i don't know the api, and there isn't much information, so I'm guessing that spinner is of type `Object`. I might be wrong though ;)

Comment: Since it's declared in the FXML file (via the `fx:id`), it must be injected in to the controller (via a `@FXML` annotation). So it just needs to be injected with the correct type, i.e. `@FXML private Spinner<Integer> spinner ;` and then `int value = spinner.getValue();` via unboxing.

Comment: @James_D you might want to make an answer yourself?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in another answer, you should never use raw types. `Spinner` is a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html): it's defined as [`Spinner<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html), where `T` is a *type parameter* that stands for "the type of the value that the spinner holds". More formally, the documentation states

> `T` - The type of all values that can be iterated through in the `Spinner`. Common types include `Integer` and `String`.

When using a class that is generic, you should always specify the type, e.g. in your case you should use

```
Spinner<Integer>
```

to refer to a spinner that iterates through integers; you should never just use the "raw type"

```
Spinner
```

Since you've defined the spinner in FXML with

```xml
<Spinner fx:id="spinner" ... >
```

you are presumably injecting it into the controller. Just use the parameterized type when you inject it:

```
public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> spinner ;

    // ...

}
```

Now the compiler is assured that `spinner` holds `Integer`s as the value, so you can just do

```
int value = spinner.getValue();
```

Also see [Java Generics: List, List<Object>, List<?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics-list-listobject-list)

Comment: Much better answer :)